# Install Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sdk

Has anyone else installed 2022 on Windows 11? Think for some blazor projects you may also have had to install .net SDK 6 and .net 6.

The installer works fine for 2019 but not 2022.

I am having an issue installing and the installer is not opening up the selection wizard. So in the first step you run vs_Community.exe or VisualStudioSetup.exe and this starts but in the second step the vs studio installer does not open and installation stops.

I've stopped ALL firewalls and virus software as well as edited the host file to pull from a different cdn.

Anything obvious I have to do?

Here is some log I found ( yaay logs :-) ) :

```
[10/14/2022, 14:0:27] === Logging started: 2022/10/14 14:00:27 ===
[10/14/2022, 14:0:27] Executable: C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\VisualStudioSetup.exe v17.3.32929.385
[10/14/2022, 14:0:27] --- logging level: standard ---
[10/14/2022, 14:0:27] Directory 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\d36c94f2e0f3c00ea1fb3af9\' has been selected for file extraction
[10/14/2022, 14:0:27] Extracting files to: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\d36c94f2e0f3c00ea1fb3af9\
[10/14/2022, 14:0:28] Extraction took 594 milliseconds
[10/14/2022, 14:0:28] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline '  --env "_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\VisualStudioSetup.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:C:\Users\Admin\Downloads"'
[10/14/2022, 14:0:34] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[10/14/2022, 14:0:34] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0xe0434f4d
[10/14/2022, 14:0:34] === Logging stopped: 2022/10/14 14:00:34 ===
```

Is it the executing extracted package failing?

UPDATE: This is for VS Studio 2022 and not VS Code. Code is fine and has no issues :-).

Comment: Are you talking about Visual Studio or Visual Studio code? These are two completely independent products and neither installs the other.

Comment: yes, many many times, without any problems; sorry if that doesn't help :shrug:

Comment: I've updated OP and it is for VS Studio 2022 not Code. Sorry for the confusion.... something does tell me it could be permissions based but I get no errors to indicate since I am admin and even tried to install from C drive. Marc can you post link to where you got your install file from?